# Ubuntu 21.10 not booting after upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, 21.10

I had upgraded from 20.04 to 21.10 recently, and it doesn't boot anymore. Images:

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

[image: Fourth]

After the mouse pointer, this (Fourth image) appears for a second, then disappears along with the mouse pointer.

Then I get a black screen and it stays like that.
Also I am booting Ubuntu from an external hard disc drive. Is there a solution for this?